# Listing pages according to the number of entries in a database using PHP

Tags: php, loops

I'm writing a code in PHP that gets the number of products in the database, and lists them in pages accordingly.
Here's the code I have so far :

```
            <?php 
                $numProds=10;
                if($numProds%9 == 0) {
                    $numPages = $numProds/9;
                } elseif ($numProds%9 != 0) { // true
                    $numPages = floor($numProds/9) + 1; // $numPages = 2;
                }
                for ($i = 1; $i < $numPages+1; $i++) {
            ?>
                <li id="page<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <?php if($numProds <= 9) {
                            for ($i = 1; $i < $numProds+1; $i++) { ?>
                                <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                    <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/sampleImg.png" /></div>
                                    <div class="prodInfo">
                                        <h2><a href="#">Red Strawberry Keyring blabla bla bla</a></h2>
                                        <b>Price: $2.50 |</b> <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            $numProds-=9;
                            for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {  ?>
                                <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                    <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/sampleImg.png" /></div>
                                    <div class="prodInfo">
                                        <h2><a href="#">Red Strawberry Keyring blabla bla bla</a></h2>
                                        <b>Price: $2.50 |</b> <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    <?php   }
                        }?>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
```

I set a test value of 10, and I want every page to include 9 products.
That means I need 2 pages; one page with 9 products and another page with only 1 product.
First, I calculate the number of pages needed, and create the pages (AKA the `li`'s).
Secondly, In each page I have two if statements:
1) If numProds is smaller or equal to 9, create the exact number of products using a loop.
2) If numProds is bigger than 9 (i.e 10), create 9 products and take 9 off numProds so $numProds will be 1, which is the only number of products that should be created on the second page.

The problem with this code is that all the pages include 9 products regardless of numProds, so something is wrong.
I went through the code a few times and found nothing.

Another problem is that in each page the `<li id="page<?php echo $i; ?>">` part starts from 0 again.
I know that's because of the loop, but my question is, is there a way to somehow continue the loop from the previous `$i` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first issue is that you're using the same counter variable in both the outer and inner loops. 
Developing from your current code - this should be the solution, there can of course be a shorter solution. 
The ifs inside the loop can be completely removed.
But developing from your logic - here is the solution (not tested) :

```
 <?php 
            $numProds=10;
            if($numProds%9 == 0) {
                $numPages = $numProds/9;
            } elseif ($numProds%9 != 0) { // true
                $numPages = floor($numProds/9) + 1; // $numPages = 2;
            }
            $count = 1;
            for ($i = 1; $i < $numPages+1; $i++) {
        ?>
            <li id="page<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php if($numProds <= 9) {
                        for ($j = 1; $j < $numProds+1; $j++) { ?>
                            <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/sampleImg.png" /></div>
                                <div class="prodInfo">
                                    <h2><a href="#">Red Strawberry Keyring blabla bla bla</a></h2>
                                    <b>Price: $2.50 |</b> <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <?php
                        }
                    } else {


                        for ($j = $count; $j < ($i-1)*10+10; $j++, $count++) {  ?>
                            <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/sampleImg.png" /></div>
                                <div class="prodInfo">
                                    <h2><a href="#">Red Strawberry Keyring blabla bla bla</a></h2>
                                    <b>Price: $2.50 |</b> <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <?php   }
                    }
                      $numProds -=  9; ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think there's a problem with this line: ` for ($j = $count; $j < ($i-1)*10; $j++, $count++)`. $i equals 1 in the first page... Also, could you please tell me how to make it shorter? I'm curious :)

Comment: Hi, I have fixed that line. Sorry for that. For a shorter version, check answer from @shadyyx . If that doesn't help, let me know.

Comment: Yea, thank you! It'd be just shorter to write `$i*10`. And yea I've read his solution, I was just wondering how he planned the array. I'm guessing $products is an array with product arrays embedded within it. Correct me if I'm wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Oh yes, $i*10. Actually, I formulated another code and then forgot to change stuff. Sorry about that. yes. $products is an array with products' info embedded - 
Array (
[0] = Array ( info for 1st product ),
[1] = Array ( info for 2nd product )
)

Comment: Okay, pretty clever :) Thanks! And since he's not answering me, maybe you could help me, what happens if there are less than 9 products? There will still be 9 divs and his code doesn't cover it...

Comment: for ($j = 1; $j <= 9; $j++) change this to  for ($j = 1; $j <= $limit; $j++)
And above that, $limit = (count($products) >= 9) ? 9 : count($products);

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was missing something!

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite the `$i` from the main `for` loop in another inner-loops...
Use another variable, like `$j` instead.
In each inner-loop You also start looping from `$i = 1` to `$i < 10` - that's why You have 9 products on each page...

Try this code:

```
        <?php 
            $numProds = 10;
            if($numProds % 9 == 0) {
                $numPages = $numProds/9;
            } elseif ($numProds%9 != 0) { // true
                $numPages = ceil($numProds/9); // $numPages = 2;
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPages; $i++) {
        ?>
            <li id="page<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php if($numProds <= 9) {
                        for ($j = 1; $j <= $numProds; $j++) { ?>
                            <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/sampleImg.png" /></div>
                                <div class="prodInfo">
                                    <h2><a href="#">Red Strawberry Keyring blabla bla bla</a></h2>
                                    <b>Price: $2.50 |</b> <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                        $numProds-=9;
                        for ($j = 1; $j < 10; $j++) {  ?>
                            <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/sampleImg.png" /></div>
                                <div class="prodInfo">
                                    <h2><a href="#">Red Strawberry Keyring blabla bla bla</a></h2>
                                    <b>Price: $2.50 |</b> <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <?php   }
                    }?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

This shoudl work...

But in real world I suppose You will have the products returned in some array, and therefore this code should be much better for Your needs:

```
        <?php 
            $numProds = count($products);
            $numPages = ceil($numProds/9);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPages; $i++) {
        ?>
            <li id="page<?php echo $i; ?>">
                 <?php for ($j = 1; $j <= 9; $j++) {
                     $product = array_shift($products); ?>
                     <div class="product" id="prodId<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
                          <div class="productImage"><img class="image" src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" /></div>
                          <div class="prodInfo">
                              <h2><a href="/path/to/products/<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"><?php echo $product['title']; ?></a></h2>
                              <b>Price: <?php echo $product['price']; ?> |</b> <a href="/add/to/cart/?p_id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't pay any attention to the indexes. And yes, I do want each page to have 9 products so it's fine. As for the arrays, you seem to have some experience with shopping sites, should I create the array for the product IDs and then retrieve all the other details for each ID or create an object in each place in the array with all the details already in it?

Comment: Okay I got it. Just one question, what if the number of products in the array is less then 9? There will still be 9 divs created...

Comment: You can create a check - if there is less than 9 products then loop not for 9 times, but for that many times as many products You have :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're making this a little more complicated than you need to, I think; instead of reducing numProds by 9 each time, pass the value between the pages and use it as an offset, to skip the products you've already seen.

On the first page of results, it'll be 0, so you can display the first 9 products. On the second page, it's 9, so you skip the first 9 products and display the next 9. On the third page, it's 18, and so on.